# Excessively long answers

Tags: discussion

I saw a new mod auto-flag today that I haven't seen to this point, an answer is "excessively long".

This is the answer:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97891/336

Now, I'm guilty of creating more than a few very long-winded answers. At which point do we need to suggest that content be moved offsite and referenced as a source? It's a good answer, it seems, but it is excessively long. It makes me concerned that other answers may be lost amid its length.

I'm asking for feedback here from the community. I'm not suggesting an action one way or another.

Comment: As the post in question is mine I feel the need to respond. It is too long, I admit and I agree it would be better as a blog article. The thing is that I do not have a blog to post on and at the time I wrote that there was no excessive information about that issue in the net (at least I couldn't find any). Once Magento team updated their docs I put the info at the top to redirect most readers to better organized source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The auto-flag is there just in case some spam (or something else that's wrong) might be hidden in the posts.
It's just a way to notify the mods to take a close look at the post.

Note: The posts are limited anyway to 30k characters.

Comment: Oh? Only 30k characters? :)

Answer (score 5):

I would say, we should not hardly enforce a limit here, just a nice comment, it could make more sense as a blog, wiki or even magento docs entry.

Theore interesting part here is: it could be copy&paste of an existing article, we should validate this possibility when the auto flag triggers

Comment: you have a point. if it is just a copy-paste, he can use the link to the original post and we can enforce it. But what about if the link broken in futrure ?

Comment: thats always a problem, even if you link to real documentation. But then also the question may be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't like too long answer like the one you have mentioned above. As a reader I find very time consuming when I am looking for some solution within my coding interval.

However, I do like to read answers with precisely explained and contains quality info when I am not in middle of writing the code or motivated to learn on the topic. I know, system wouldn't know what reader want.

I would suggest to have the option of setting exact answer part at top and then link to click where all other explanation and information are kept.

Just my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

In my honest opinion, we should not put a limit on the answer. If the content is good, then do not even think about flag that answer. Instead we need to congrats him/her for his valuable answer with our upvotes.

Comment: Even if the length of the answer makes it difficult for someone to see another, more concise answer?

Comment: @philwinkle it is the content that matters not the length. Length of an answer is depending on the question's broadness. It has nothing to do with a resourceful answer. if an answer is too long and it seems to be the right answer then that means the question is too broad. doesn't it ?

Comment: The flag is done automatically. It's not a limit, it's a flag and nobody did it, it's automated to help in review.